# Изменение на всех страницах

Tags: html, css

Хочу, чтобы на всех страницах сайта отображались одни и те же новости, при изменении только на одной. Уже задавал вопрос, но не много недопонял, подскажите.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="newsblock"><?php include "news.html"; ?></div>
  <div class="main_area">
    ....
  </div>
</body>
```

Вроде бы всё так и сделал как указано в коде. создал news.html. Но текст на этой странице почему-то не отображается. Быть может что-то добавить надо?

Answer (score 1):

Если не пойдет айфрейм, то предлагаю на пхп.
Надо создать Index.php в нем написать весь ваш код из index.html
и лучше news.html - тоже переделать в php.

Если пойдете дальше кодить то сделайте просто шаблон типо(пхп просто склеит код всех этих файлов в 1 файл index.php):

header.php:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="newsblock">
```

index.php:

```
<? include header.php ?>
<? include news.php ?>
<? include page.php ?>
<? include footer.php ?>
```

page.php:

```
 </div>
 <div class="main_area">
 ....
 </div>
```

footer.php:

```
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо php. Будьте проще - используйте [<iframe>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe) или на худой конец [<frame>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/frame)

Answer (score 0):

to [danpetruk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8694/danpetruk) Фрэймы ;D lol

Автор настрой сервер что бы php код обрабатывался не только из *.php* файлов (для тебя надо и *.html* )